# Can Delphi 4 Pro be installed and used reliably on Windows XP (or later)?

Tags: delphi, windows-xp, compatibility, backwards-compatibility, windows-98

Several years ago I used Delphi 4 Pro on a Windows '98 SE machine to create Delphi projects.

Would it be feasible to install the same Delphi 4 Pro on a Windows XP machine (or later OS, such as Windows 7) to view and update older Delphi projects?

Comment: i had experience to install Delphi 5 to Win2K and winXP. /// 

If D4 is similar, then the major problem would be long paths with spaces.  So - go control panel for `System Properties` and check OS `environment variables` like TEMP, TMP, etc. Set them to short paths like `c:\temp` or `c:\windows\temp` and fix ACLs to give ur user access to those. Then install Delphi in `Advanced` mode into paths like `C:\Delphi`. That should include everything, IDE itself, documentation, BDE and other common files, InstallShield - everything. After that i think D4 would work. At least D5 worked.

Comment: It's no problem at all to install to a location with spaces in the name. No problem installing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\....

Comment: @david i'm afraid of I/O restrictions at `Program Files` introduced in XP, especialyl if one would install 3rd-party components that had habit of installign into Delphi sub-folder. So it would be better to play on safe side, it does not cost much to change install paths once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run Delphi 4 on a variety of 32 bit operating systems without any problems, including 32 bit XP and Win7.

However, on 64-bit Windows 7, and other 64 bit varieties of Windows, including Windows Server 2008 R2, I have found that it is difficult to install, and does not run very well at all.

Moving your existing Delphi 4 code up to Delphi 2007 is probably not going to be very hard though. You should probably consider that option as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  How about moving Delphi 4 projects to Free Pascal (from www.freepascal.org)?  As it is Pascal (like Delphi), free open source, and actively supports current operating systems.

Comment: Your mileage may vary, but for my apps it's basically somewhere between a total rewrite, and a 90% rewrite, in cases I've seen, unless your app is really really trivial, you're far better off buying XE3 and staying with Delphi.  While the FreePascal language dialect is very close to Delphi, the LCL  (Lazarus) and VCL (Delphi) are very different, and most third party components for the VCL can not be ported at all to the LCL.

Answer (score 1):

[How to install Delphi 4 in windows 7(32 bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990746/how-to-install-delphi-4-in-windows-732-bit)

Exact same question, check there for an answer, at the worst you will have to run VM.